# Android Screen on laptop using WiFi display

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtsp, rtp, mplayer

I want to display Android device screen on my laptop using "wifi-display". According to documentation protocol is familiar to rtsp. I made a lot of debugging and almost done. I do not want to use wifi-direct.

I made three point structure:

1. tablet running: wfd -l 0.0.0.0:8888 
   (no output)
2. mplayer running: mplayer -v -v -v rtsp://localhost:8888/ 
   output: http://pastebin.com/hLU0cSKQ
3. my proxy app running the same machine running mplayer:
   output: http:// pastebin.com/snRUCa22

Proxy app output shows all messages sent from proxy side:

1. mplayer rec - received from mplayer
2. mplayer send - send to mplayer
3. wfd rec - received from wfd
4. wfd send - send to wfd

Log is similar to: https://github.com/kensuke/How-to-Miracast-on-AOSP/wiki/RTSP-log

After connection negotiation mplayer (vlc player also) does not display anything, but wireshark shows many UDP packages send to from tablet to mplayer on ports defined in connection negotiation.

Does "DESCRIBE" response is correct? Is it to simple?
Does WiDi uses some "standard" UDP communication?
Does the communication look ok?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions, and this does not appear to be about some app that you are developing.

Comment: Yes it's about my proxy app which I develop.